# Vaule javascript to php echo

Tags: javascript, php, loops

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      var x;
      var test = '';
      var y = 0;
      var a = 0;
      day = 5;

      for (i = 0; i < day; i++) 
      {
        y++;
        a++;
        test = test + '<b>Masa Hari '+ y +' </b>- Masa Dari : <input type="text" placeholder="contoh 16:30" name="masakursus[]" value="<?php echo ' + a +'." ".$masakursus1['+ a +']; ?>"/> Masa Hingga : <input placeholder="contoh 16:30" type="text" name="masakursus[]" value="<?php echo $masakursus1[10];?>"/></br>';
      }

      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =test;
  });
</script>
```

is it possible to put the value of `var a` into `var test`.? I want to view output from array php.

Comment: Yes, you can do this. But why not put the loop in PHP instead of JS?

Comment: What do you mean by "put value var a into var test."? That code looks wrong in many way, maybe you should split it up completely into PHP, JS and HTML parts...

Comment: You can store your php array to js variable. And use the js variable on the loop.

Comment: No. What you want with this `value="<?php echo ' + a +'." ".$masakursu` is not possible. PHP is interpreted on the server, JS is in the browser. Every time PHP is encountered (between <?php and ?>), that block is interpreted on the server. Anything else is just sent as is to the browser. JS only starts after it's received from the server. So you can see how the PHP part of the code had already run when the JS is executed. In other words, you CANNOT pass data from JS to PHP directly.